# how to join eav table in table_method

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, entity-attribute-value

I have the following schema.yml:

```
JosJeventsVevdetail:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: jos_jevents_vevdetail
  columns:
    evdet_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    rawdata:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    CustomField: { class: JosJeventsVevdetail, local: evdet_id, foreign: evdet_id, type: one, foreignType: many }


JosJevCustomfield:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: jos_jev_customfields
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    evdet_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: ''
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    value:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
```

I.e. there are many name/value pairs that are matched with a single record in JosJeventsVevdetail.

I'm trying to flatten this with a table method ( and some other tables) like this:

```
return $q->
    innerJoin("$rootAlias.Event e")->
    innerJoin("e.EventDetail ed")->
    innerJoin("ed.CustomField cf")->
    innerJoin("$rootAlias.JoomlaUser u")->
    innerJoin("u.Person p")->
    innerJoin("$rootAlias.Status s")->
    innerJoin("$rootAlias.RsvpType rt")->
    addWhere("cf.name=?",'preconExams')-> //this removed works,but query wrong
    addSelect("$rootAlias.*, e.*, ed.*, s.*, rt.*, u.*, p.*, cf.*");
```

but I get an error message "Unknown column name". When I remove cf.name='preconExams', the query runs, but jos_jev_customfields is not joined in the query.

Is there anything wrong with the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is wrong is the class of your relation. It shoud be `JosJevCustomfield` and you've put `JosJeventsVevdetail` ;-) . `JosJeventsVevdetail` has no column `name`, hence the error.